# Issue with Gmail chat in google chrome

Tags: gmail, chat

I am having issues with my Gmail chat window in Google Chrome. The chat window is not appearing fully.

Please see the attached image. Is there any way to fix this. Even when my Google Chrome window is not in maximized state, I am having the problem.

[image: Gmail-chat issue]

[Edit]
OS: Windows 7
Chrome Version: 20.0.1132.57 m

The issue remains even if I log in using a different account. But with Internet Explorer 9, Gmail chat is working fine.

Also tried resetting the browser (deleted firstrun.bat 0kb file) and still the issue is not fixed.

Comment: Can you repeat this behaviour in another browser? Under a different user? What have you tried?

Comment: Tried with internet explorer and working fine in ie9

Comment: Did you clear the Chrome cache? Reset the browser? Anything like that?

Comment: @RandolphWest Even after resetting the browser and clearing the cache, i am having the issue.  I have also tried with a different gmail account.

Comment: Try with disabling adblock if you have.